# MYSQL get all user rows having second max salary

Tags: mysql

I found many questions for finding  - second max salary for employees. But in all these posts, only salary is selecting.

```
select max(salary) from user
WHERE salary NOT IN (SELECT max(salary) from user)
```

I need all **users rows** having second max salary.

> sample user table

```
id       name       salary
------------------------------------
1         A             100
2        B              200
3        C              50
4        D              200
5        E              100
```

> and my expected result is,

```
id       name       salary
------------------------------------
1        A             100
5        E             100
```

Comment: You can also use  `SELECT * FROM user WHERE salary = (SELECT DISTINCT(salary) FROM user order by salary DESC LIMIT 1,1 )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use two subqueries to isolate the second highest salary, e.g.

```
SELECT id, name, salary
FROM user
WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM user WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM user));
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that if you are using MySQL 8+, and are open to using analytic functions, then `DENSE_RANK` really helps here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, name, salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) dr
    FROM user
)

SELECT id, name, salary
FROM cte
WHERE dr = 2;
```

Comment: I don't like the first solution, only because it's not obviously scalable to 3rd, 4th highest salary, etc.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes...this is one reason why analytic functions were introduced into SQL to handle this types of problems. Yes

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below

```
SELECT * 
FROM   user 
WHERE  salary = (SELECT salary 
                 FROM   user 
                 GROUP  BY salary 
                 ORDER  BY salary DESC 
                 LIMIT  1, 1)
```

Answer (score -3):

you will get 2nd max salary by this query

```
SELECT salary FROM user ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1, 1;
```

Comment: there can be more than 1 user with same salary.